# Vertical Menu bar in Dot Net Nuke

Tags: asp.net, css, menu, dotnetnuke, skins

I am using Dot Net Nuke community version to build my web site. I am very new to programming and DNN.
When i add a new page the menu is displayed horizontal like 
HOME | CONTACT US | ABOUT US |  CAREERS
I want to display it as a vertical menu like

HOME
CONTACT US
ABOUT US
CAREERS

How am i supposed to do it???
I tried a few menu modules like codingstaff.MenuBox but that dint help me either.

Is there a good site that can help me learn DNN as a beginner ???
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To display a vertical menu, I'm afraid you need to develop a new set skin which use SOLPARTMENU or TREEVIEW take place of MENU.

Answer (score 0):

hey sayed this is the best solution for ur question.

Contain the menu in a   that has its own styling - width, etc.  Then place the following into that div: